# how to get a child process memory usage in node.js?

Tags: node.js, memory-management, child-process

I know there is a api process.memoryUsage() to get memory usage in current process.

But if I start a new child process by child_process.spawn(command, [args], [options]) and I get a ChildProcess object, then how can I get the new process memory usage?

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to get child's memoryUsage is installing pidusage

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pidusage

In the console write this to install it:

In Windows Command: npm i pidusage --save
In Mac Command :  sudo npm i pidusage --save

```
let pidusage = require('pidusage');

const cp = require("child_process");

const child = cp.spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

pidusage(child.pid, function (err, stats) {

console.log(stats);

});
/*
Output: 
{
   cpu: 10.0,            // percentage (from 0 to 100*vcore)
   memory: 357306368,    // bytes
   ppid: 312,            // PPID
   pid: 727,             // PID
   ctime: 867000,        // ms user + system time
   elapsed: 6650000,     // ms since the start of the process
   timestamp: 864000000  // ms since epoch
}
*/
```

If you want to get more than one child's memoryUsage you need to change child.pid for and array [child.pid,child2.pid], function (err, stats) ...

Comment: Actually this approach does not take into account case when child process itself creates processes. In this case it is better to use `pidusage-tree.

Comment: Is this a suitable approach to limiting a child process resource usage? For example, if a child process memory usage reaches x bytes, then I would like to stop the process.

Comment: That depends on what you are doing, because if you have a process to do just a simple task then you won't need to do that, but if you got a web server for example that receive a lot of requests and you want to dedicate a specific amount of **memory or cpu** you can do so, nothing stop you from doing it.

Answer (score 7):

We can get **multiplatform** solution with using nodejs ipc protocol. you just need to setup event for requesting memory usage from parent process, and then send `process.memoryUsage()` from spawned child process.

parent.js

```
var ChildProcess = require('child_process'),
    child = ChildProcess.fork('./child.js');

child.on('message', function(payload){
    console.log(payload.memUsage);
});

child.send('get_mem_usage');
```

and in `child.js` it might look like this

```
process.on('message', function(msg){
    if(msg === 'get_mem_usage'){
         process.send({memUsage: process.memoryUsage()});
    }
});
```

Comment: This only works when the child is also a Node script (`fork`), but the OP asked about an arbitrary process (`spawn`).

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `ps`(uses `/proc/<pid>/stat` underlying) if you are in a unix environment. Here's an example:

```
// Spawn a node process
var child_process = require('child_process');
var child = child_process.spawn('node');

// Now get its pid.
child_process.exec('ps -p' + child.pid + ' -o vsize=',  function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  err = err || stderr;
  if (err) {
      return console.log('BAD Luck buddy: ', err);
  }
  console.log('YOU\'ve done it', parseInt(stdout, 10));
});
```

This is tested with ubuntu 12.04 and OS X lion. Though don't think it'll work in windows.