# How to access the process object of child process [Node]

Tags: node.js, child-process

So basically I am making a process class so I can spawn custom processes with ease later on. I want to access the `process` object of the child process however I cannot do that for some reason. My code:

```js
let cp = require("child_process")
class Process {
    constructor(path, args) {
        this.spawnedProcess = cp.fork(path, args)
    }
    
    getMemoryUsage() {
        return this.spawnedProcess.memoryUsage() //errors here
    }

}
```

`TypeError: this.spawnedProcess.memoryUsage is not a function`

How can i access the process object of a forked child process?

EDIT:
I have also tried the following
`this.spawnedProcess.process.memoryUsage()` (errors with saying process is undefined)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730429/how-to-get-a-child-process-memory-usage-in-node-js

Comment: You're welcome. No problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in [how to get a child process memory usage in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730429/how-to-get-a-child-process-memory-usage-in-node-js), here is a way to it using `pidusage`.

```js
let pidusage = require('pidusage');

const cp = require("child_process");

const child = cp.spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

pidusage(child.pid, function (err, stats) {

console.log(stats);

});
/*
Output: 
{
   cpu: 10.0,            // percentage (from 0 to 100*vcore)
   memory: 357306368,    // bytes
   ppid: 312,            // PPID
   pid: 727,             // PID
   ctime: 867000,        // ms user + system time
   elapsed: 6650000,     // ms since the start of the process
   timestamp: 864000000  // ms since epoch
}
*/
```